# "Query is not understandable (4000)" error on view refresh

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have the following two lines of code:

```
    Set customerView = db.GetView ("(Lookup - Customers by Reference)")
    Call customerView.refresh()
```

Very occasionally, the 2nd line will give users an **Error 4000, Query is not understandable**

Restarting Notes gets rid of it, but it *sometimes* comes back for a couple of users.

This has only recently started happening, and I've not made any changes to the view.

**EDIT**

To explain further, nowhere in the function that is throwing the error is there any code relating to a FT Search, which makes me think that this may be an error that IBM have stuffed up in R9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Check Forms and Fields (especialy fields!) you use in search formula of the view.
Maybe you search text value in non-text fields.
Fields are shared between forms, i.e field is unique not within form, field is unique within NSF. So, first time you create field - NSF writes it's properties (field type included) in NSF structure. And if you have two forms containing field with same name, but with different types (text and non-text) - you'll get this error.
I saw this error several times, and every time it was caused by FT-queries or search formulas what tries to search some text value in field, that initialy was created as non-text (date or numbers field).
If this is the case... Well, it's hard to get rid of this error. Basically you'll have to delete this field from every form and every document in nsf, then compact it using copy-style, then recreate field in right type and restore it's values in docs using right type - it helps usually.

Comment: I'm not doing any searching, so I don't have a search formula.
I believe it's an incorrect error message, and that I should be getting a different message. Error 4000 seems to cover a lot of things.